# Variation in iOS 6 & iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, uinavigationbar

Newbie here learning programming. I created a table and a detail view. Once I click a row, it will direct to the detail view which shows detail info of that row. I also maintain a navigation bar on top. This all works fine.

However, once I click into the detail view. The Behavior of *iOS6* and *7* is different. In *6*, it seems like the view is placed nicely below the navigation bar. But in *7*, the view is like placed right under the bar.

What is wrong?

Comment: While it might not be possible could you provide some screen shots to see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your view:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow this solves my problem! However, now there's another one. I put a toolbar at the bottom, and now it places differently in iOS6 & 7.

So actually what's going on in this case? How come things look different in different OS? I believe everything should look the same for spacing.